# Create WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.1.0 docker image from macOS Ventura

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

i try create a docker image for do an container execute WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.1.0 but the problem is that i use macOS Ventura and for my system dont exist image base; how to make it a docker image for my WSO2 Enterprise Integrator instalation from my macOS System?

```
2023-06-04 01:28:57 Starting wso2ei (starting from launchd).
2023-06-04 01:28:57 sudo: launchctl: command not found
```

and i have understand that this error message is because the ¨launchctl¨ command only exist in macOS enviroment and the Docker images base only are based in the Windows and Linux operative systems, my unique option is modify the sh code for can run correctly?? really i need run 3 sh scripts where are a one for each tool, in this ask i stay focused in the first tool component tha
t is Micro Integrator and his script for start the server is the next:

```
ok
#!/bin/sh
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2019, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved.
#
# WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
# Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
# in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Launchctl commands wrapper for WSO2 product services in macOS

VERSION=7.1.0
PRODUCT=wso2ei
SERVICE_NAME_FILE=org.wso2.ei710.mi.dashboard.plist
SERVICE_NAME=$(echo $SERVICE_NAME_FILE | rev | cut -f2- -d. | rev)

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting ${PRODUCT} (starting from launchd)."
        sudo launchctl start ${SERVICE_NAME}
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping ${PRODUCT} (stoping from launchd)."
        sudo launchctl stop ${SERVICE_NAME}
        ;;
    restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
    status)
        echo "PID | Last Exit Status | Process"
        STATUS="$(sudo launchctl list | grep ${SERVICE_NAME})"
        echo ${STATUS}
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: ${PRODUCT}-${VERSION}-service {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

My docker build script is the next

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:8-jdk-hotspot

# Instala el paquete sudo
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y sudo

# Establece el directorio de trabajo dentro del contenedor
WORKDIR /opt/wso2ei

# Copia los archivos de WSO2 Enterprise Integrator a la imagen de Docker
COPY 7.1.0/ .

# Expone los puertos necesarios para WSO2 Enterprise Integrator
EXPOSE 9443 9763

# Comando de inicio de WSO2 Enterprise Integrator
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/opt/wso2ei/launchd/service_micro_integrator.sh", "start"]
```

Ok,
you believe that is posible modify the code for can execute correctly the sh script in Docker container?? or is viable or posible have that do this but from in a Linux based distribution for dont have "launchtl¨ command problema? i going to thank very full if anyone orient to me, please help to me to dissapear the confusion in my problem, so thanks very much,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really have to create a docker file from scratch. You can use the official WSO2 base image from the docker hub. Also, if you want to create a Docker image from scratch take a look at [this](https://github.com/wso2/docker-ei/tree/master/dockerfiles/alpine/micro-integrator) repo.

Comment: ok thanks, but what version is? I need the 7.1.0 and this repo don't indicates which version is :(

Comment: @JesusRed This is the base image https://hub.docker.com/layers/wso2/wso2mi/1.2.0/images/sha256-0211440192abd494d0489333a7ac26fcab72ed8d35c8400333251e2ddcf37390?context=explore and this is the relevant branch https://github.com/wso2/docker-ei/tree/7.1.x

Comment: A ok, i understand, i read correctlly the documentation, i do solve my ask correctly, thanks for you now have my WSO2 docker container run, thanks for all.